# ANTLR4 parser crashing on _errHandler->sync( )

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have a parser grammar with rules like these:

```
tokens_statement_1 : 
TOK_01 | TOK_02 | TOK_03
  ;
tokens_statement_2 : 
TOK_04 | TOK_05 | TOK_06
  ;
    
rule_1 
@init
{
  // Some C++ code
} :

  statement1=tokens_statement_1
  {
    // Some C++ code
  }
  (
    statement2=tokens_statement_2
    {
      // Some C++ code
    }
  )*
  ;
```

Now, if I'm missing tokens from the **optional** `token_statement_2` part, I'm getting a crash:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  bitset::set: __position (which is 1138) >= _Nb (which is 1048)
```

Taking a closer look in gdb, the crash is happening in the `sync` method in the error handler, right after this block:

```
  statement1=tokens_statement_1
  {
    // Some C++ code
  }
```

`Generated C++ code`

```
   ...
   setState(158);
   _errHandler->sync(this);  // CRASHES HERE
   alt = getInterpreter<atn::ParserATNSimulator>()->adaptivePredict(_input, 94, _ctx);
   ...
```

My question is, do I need to override the ErrorStrategy to avoid this? Shouldn't the DefaultErrorStrategy handle this and try token insertion/deletion?

Any help will be appreciated!

[Added call stack]

```
#5  0x00007fd734224713 in __cxa_throw ()
  .../64bit/libboost_program_options-mt-d-x64.so.1.79.0
#6  0x00007fd73427dd35 in std::__throw_out_of_range_fmt(char const*, ...) ()
   from libboost_program_options-mt-d-x64.so.1.79.0
#7  0x00007fd733bc2303 in std::bitset<2048ul>::_M_check (this=0x7ffda80e2660, __position=1138, 
    __s=0x7fd733c92fae "bitset::set")
    at .../include/c++/7.3.0/bitset:769
#8  0x00007fd733bc227f in std::bitset<2048ul>::set (this=0x7ffda80e2660, __position=1138, 
    __val=true)
    at .../include/c++/7.3.0/bitset:1083
#9  0x00007fd733c1b4d9 in (anonymous namespace)::LL1AnalyzerImpl::LOOK (this=0x7ffda80e2650, 
    s=0x561d4521c710, stopState=0x0, ctx=...)
    at .../antlr_4_10_1_build/runtime/src/atn/LL1Analyzer.cpp:122
#10 0x00007fd733c1b5a3 in (anonymous namespace)::LL1AnalyzerImpl::LOOK (this=0x7ffda80e2650, 
    s=0x561d4521c6a0, stopState=0x0, ctx=...)
    at .../antlr_4_10_1_build/runtime/src/atn/LL1Analyzer.cpp:128
#11 0x00007fd733c1b605 in (anonymous namespace)::LL1AnalyzerImpl::LOOK (this=0x7ffda80e2650, 
    s=0x561d4521c9b0, stopState=0x0, ctx=...)
    at .../antlr_4_10_1_build/runtime/src/atn/LL1Analyzer.cpp:133
#12 0x00007fd733c1b605 in (anonymous namespace)::LL1AnalyzerImpl::LOOK (this=0x7ffda80e2650, 
    s=0x561d450e3de0, stopState=0x0, ctx=...)
    at .../antlr_4_10_1_build/runtime/src/atn/LL1Analyzer.cpp:133
#13 0x00007fd733c1b4fe in (anonymous namespace)::LL1AnalyzerImpl::LOOK (this=0x7ffda80e2650, 
    s=0x561d4521cf20, stopState=0x0, ctx=...)
    at .../antlr_4_10_1_build/runtime/src/atn/LL1Analyzer.cpp:123
#14 0x00007fd733c1b605 in (anonymous namespace)::LL1AnalyzerImpl::LOOK (this=0x7ffda80e2650, 
    s=0x561d4521cf90, stopState=0x0, ctx=...)
    at .../antlr_4_10_1_build/runtime/src/atn/LL1Analyzer.cpp:133
#15 0x00007fd733c1b605 in (anonymous namespace)::LL1AnalyzerImpl::LOOK (this=0x7ffda80e2650, 
    s=0x561d4521d080, stopState=0x0, ctx=...)
    at .../antlr_4_10_1_build/runtime/src/atn/LL1Analyzer.cpp:133
#16 0x00007fd733c1b605 in (anonymous namespace)::LL1AnalyzerImpl::LOOK (this=0x7ffda80e2650, 
    s=0x561d4521ce40, stopState=0x0, ctx=...)
    at .../antlr_4_10_1_build/runtime/src/atn/LL1Analyzer.cpp:133
#17 0x00007fd733c1b605 in (anonymous namespace)::LL1AnalyzerImpl::LOOK (this=0x7ffda80e2650, 
    s=0x561d4521cdc0, stopState=0x0, ctx=...)
    at .../antlr_4_10_1_build/runtime/src/atn/LL1Analyzer.cpp:133
#18 0x00007fd733c1bb31 in antlr4::atn::LL1Analyzer::LOOK (this=0x7ffda80e2838, s=0x561d4521cdc0, 
    stopState=0x0, ctx=0x0)
    at .../antlr_4_10_1_build/runtime/src/atn/LL1Analyzer.cpp:187
#19 0x00007fd733c1ba64 in antlr4::atn::LL1Analyzer::LOOK (this=0x7ffda80e2838, s=0x561d4521cdc0, 
    ctx=0x0)
    at .../antlr_4_10_1_build/runtime/src/atn/LL1Analyzer.cpp:180
#20 0x00007fd733bf69af in antlr4::atn::ATN::nextTokens (this=0x561d450d1970, s=0x561d4521cdc0, 
    ctx=0x0) at .../antlr_4_10_1_build/runtime/src/atn/ATN.cpp:35
#21 0x00007fd733bf6a2c in antlr4::atn::ATN::nextTokens (this=0x561d450d1970, s=0x561d4521cdc0)
    at .../antlr_4_10_1_build/runtime/src/atn/ATN.cpp:43
#22 0x00007fd733bbe816 in antlr4::DefaultErrorStrategy::sync (this=0x561d44fcec50, 
    recognizer=0x7ffda80e2ec0)
```

Comment: The error recovery only applies to parse errors, not any other exception. To debug this problem you could disable all the C++ code to see if things go smoother then.

Comment: I tried that (commenting out the C++ code) but the error still happens. Is there any way to know the expected token(s) when executing the sync( ) and the LA(1) inside it ?

Comment: What's the call stack of the crash? What version of Antlr4 are you using?

Comment: I'm using Antlr 4.10.1. I've drilled down a bit more and noticed it crashes here  (DefaultErrorStrategy.cpp) ```auto nextTokens = recognizer->getATN().nextTokens(s);```

Comment: Also added call stack to post

Comment: It's trying to create an error message on what tokens it can expect next. But, it's having a problem doing that. The bit set, calledRuleStack, is 2048 bits in size, and it's trying to set bit 1138 (the rule index), but can't. It looks like you are using gcc 7.3. That's ancient, and probably supports c++17 not that well. My recommendation is to move to at least version 9.

Comment: Thanks, will try that. For the moment I'm just overriding the Error Strategy and using an empty sync( ).